# Azure Search - AzureSearch_SkipContent

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have some very large blobs, so I set `AzureSearch_SkipContent` on the blob row with the following code :

```
if (b.Properties.Length >= 134217728)
{
    b.Metadata["AzureSearch_SkipContent"] = "true";
    await b.SetMetadataAsync();
}
```

But when I review the warning and errors I can see that the  indexer has attempted to index the content even though I have asked it to skip, the error I see is (this is under errors, so I guess it's not going to index anything for this blob) :

```
{
    "key": null,
    "errorMessage": "The blob '113443f46d1b184650bf4b0d5b0b3806055c43558a676b778de13f1b7ef4da93' has the size of 218285352 bytes, which exceeds the maximum size for document extraction for your current service tier."
},
```

If I look at this blob in storage explorer I see

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE Jan 3, 2018**

To make this scenario work gracefully, we are adding `indexStorageMetadataOnlyForOversizedDocuments` indexer configuration setting. It takes a bool value and is `false` by default, so set it to `true` in the indexer configuration to enable it. This is fresh off the presses and will be deployed in production worldwide by January 19.

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**

Both `"true"` and `"True"` are valid values of `AzureSearch_SkipContent`. The problem is that `AzureSearch_SkipContent` does **not** mean that the blob content is ignored.

Blob content contributes in two ways:

1. Metadata like author, date modified, etc.
2. Text content of the document.

`AzureSearch_SkipContent` means that Azure Search only performs #1 and not #2, but the blob still needs to be downloaded, so blob size quota comes into play.

Currently, the only other per-blob processing option is `AzureSearch_Skip`, which completely skips the blob. You can also use `MaxFailedItems` / `MaxFailedItemsPerBatch` to a specific number of errors, as described in [Dealing with errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#dealing-with-errors).

I think what would be really useful for this situation is the ability for Azure Search to automatically extract only the storage metadata for large blobs, without you having to process all of your blobs individually. Please feel free to add a suggestion for this on our [User Voice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Comment: I think the docs need a little work, so simple table would help.

Comment: love the fact that you people are listening, I was going to add it to uservoice just got a load of other stuff on my list right now.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to a capital **T** in `true`

```
if (b.Properties.Length >= 134217728)
{
    b.Metadata["AzureSearch_SkipContent"] = "True";
    await b.SetMetadataAsync();
}
```

When in doubt use the literal and convert to string

```
b.Metadata["AzureSearch_SkipContent"] = true.ToString();
```

or

```
bool skipIndex = true;
b.Metadata["AzureSearch_SkipContent"] = skipIndex.ToString();
```

Comment: If this is true, then docs need an update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#controlling-which-parts-of-the-blob-are-indexed

Comment: well, LOL :D This Truly Has Put a DENT In My Post Christmas Spirit :D thanks for a very quick reply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it, I had trouble as well., but I'm double checking it now.

Comment: I am just updating my 1 million blobs, so I will also soon find out.

Comment: My testing confirms this is the issue with AzureSearch_Skip/AzureSearch_SkipContent, but oddly my soft delete metadata property is not case sensitive.